# Why are not all Stack Exchange sites available for migrating off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, migration, off-topic

I encountered today the following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091802/given-x-0-and-x-n1-and-that-x-i-is-integer-how-to-calculate-sumx-0x-1-x-n

Because it should be asked in Math.SE site. I voted to close it. You can select it should be posted into one of five other forums, but https://math.stackexchange.com/ is not possible to select. Why are not all Stack Exchange sites available?

Comment: Just flag it for migration.

Comment: @hims056 means flag, choose "Other" and explain where and why you think it should be migrated to. :)

Comment: Do note that the moderators of the target site may not agree and reject the migration.

Comment: @Oded not only moderators, 3K users can also close the question on the target site (like any other question) causing the migration to be rejected.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - True. But when flagging with Other, moderators tend to talk to each other and the rejection will happen at that stage, before an actual migration occurs.

Comment: @Oded nice, wasn't aware of that. To be picky, you mean the flag will be declined. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - that too ;)

Comment: Flag is there to be abused! On my other 15K+ rep account, I see plenty of flags ignored ... just saying ...